# get foreign table assoc PDO SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo, foreign-keys

im trying to obtain a table name of foreign assoc in mysql with PDO.
for example, i have:

users table

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key |  AI | Foreign Keys   |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
| id         | int(255) | NO   | PRI | yes |                |
| username   | char(16) | NO   |     |     |                |
| password   | char(32) | NO   | UNI |     |                |
| group      | int(255) | NO   | MUL |     | mytable.group  |
| created    | datetime | NO   |     |     |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
```

group table

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key |  AI | Foreign Keys   |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
| id         | int(255) | NO   | PRI | YES |                |
| name       | char(16) | NO   | UNI |     |                |
| description| TEXT     | YES  |     |     |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-----+----------------+
```

I want to obtain the name of foreign table assoc(users.group => group ) dinamically.
SHOW COLUMNS and DESCRIBE commands doesnt show a assoc.

If anyone knows how to do it I will be very grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: Why was that down voted?, because i correctly answer a hard question? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHOW CREATE TABLE users, shows all the info of the table, but not in an organized array. I found a method to obtain all assoc data dynamically with SQL:

```
SELECT 
      ke.column_name col, 
      ke.referenced_table_schema assoc_db,
      ke.referenced_table_name assoc_table,
      ke.referenced_column_name assoc_col
FROM
      information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke
WHERE
      ke.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL              
AND   ke.table_schema='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND   ke.table_name='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

My example will return:

```
array(
      public 'col' => string 'group' (length=5) //field with foreign data
      public 'assoc_db' => string 'mytable' (length=6)  //foreign db 
      public 'assoc_table' => string 'group' (length=5) //foreign table
      public 'assoc_col' => string 'id' (length=2) //foreign field
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users
```

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE users, shows all the info of table, but not in organized array.